# If $x\in L$ lies in exactly one Cartan subalgebra, then $x$ is regular

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

> (*Question 15.3 in Humphreys's book Introduction to Lie Algebras*) Let $L$ be semisimple (char $\mathbb F = 0$), $x\in L$ semisimple. Prove that if $x$ lies in exactly one CSA (Cartan subalgebra), then $x$ is regular.

**Definitions.** An element $x$ is said regular if $C_L(x) = \{y\in L: [y,x] = 0\}$ is a maximal toral subalgebra. In particular, when $L$ is semisimple, being maximal toral is equivalent to being a CSA which is equivalent to being a minimal Engel subalgebra.
An Engel subalgebra is one of the form $L_0(\mbox{ad }x) = \{y \in L: (\mbox{ad }x)^ky =0 \mbox{ for some integer } k \}, x\in L$.

**Remark.** This question have been asked here [Cartan Subalgebra and regular elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428558/cartan-subalgebra-and-regular-elements) and here [$x$ regular $\Leftrightarrow$ $x$ is in exactly one CSA](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279641/x-regular-leftrightarrow-x-is-in-exactly-one-csa). Both of them lack of an answer. Moreover, the suggestion given in the latter is in my opinion wrong, since taking "*$y\in C_L(x)\setminus H$ such that $L_0(\mbox{ad }y)$ is minimal*" (I'm assuming he meant minimal among all the $y\in C_L(x)\setminus H$) does not ensure that it is minimal among all Engel subalgebras. I've tried to work a little bit more with this argument as follows. Of course, if $L_0(\mbox{ad }y)$ is not minimal, it will contain a minimal Engel subalgebra, say $L_0(\mbox{ad }z)$ ($L$ has finite dimension). But I can't see how to argue that $x\in L_0(\mbox{ad } z)$ to obtain the absurd of $x$ lying both in $H$ and $L_0(\mbox{ad } z)$.

**Some ideas.** Suppose $x$ is not regular. On one hand, being semisimple implies that $C_L(x) = L_0(\mbox{ad } x)$. Furthermore, there exists a maximal toral $H\subseteq C_L(x),$ where $H$ is the subalgebra spanned by the semisimple elements of $L$. Since $H = C_L(H)$, it follows that $x\in H$. On the other hand, $x$ being irregular implies that $L_0(\mbox{ad }x) = C_L(x)$ is not miminal, so let us take $L_0(\mbox{ad }y)\subseteq C_L(x)$ properly and minimal. In particular, $y\in C_L(x)$ gives us that $x\in L_0(\mbox{ad }y).$  Both $H$ and $L_0(\mbox{ad }y)$ are CSA, so it remains to prove that they are not the same to obtain a contradiction. $H$ and $L_0(\mbox{ad }y)$ are too generic, I can't see a way to argue that. I'm stuck and out of ideas.

Any insight or help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $x\in\mathfrak{a}$ is the Cartan subalgebra. Note that we can decompose $L=L_0\oplus\bigoplus_{\lambda\in\Omega}L_\lambda$ for some finite set $\Omega\subseteq\mathfrak{a}^*$ that does not contain $0$ ($L_\lambda$ are the eigenspaces of the pairwise commuting operators $ad(h), h\in\mathfrak{a}$). But, $L_0=\mathfrak{a}$ since Cartan subalgebras are self-centralizing (I think this fact is proved in Chapter 8). I claim that $\lambda(x)\neq 0$ for $\lambda\in\Omega$. Indeed, if $\lambda(x)=0$, then $ad(x)$ annihilates $L_\lambda$ <s>so $L_\lambda+\mathbb{F}x$ contains an abelian subalgebra of dimension at least $2$ and contains $x$ (Take an element $y\in L_\lambda$, form $\mathbb{F}x+\mathbb{F}y$).</s> so there exists $0\neq y\in L_\lambda$ such that $ad(x)(y)=\lambda(x)y=0$. Pick $h\in\mathfrak{a}$, $z\in L_{-\lambda}$ such that $y,h,z$ is an $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ triple, i.e. $$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\mapsto y,\quad\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\mapsto h,\quad\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\mapsto z
$$ is an isomorphism between $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and $\mathbb{F}y+\mathbb{F}h+\mathbb{F}z$. Note that $y+z$ is semisimple since its preimage in $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ is semisimple. Moreover, $x$ commutes with $y+z$, so $\mathbb{F}x+\mathbb{F}(y+z)$ is abelian and contains semisimple elements. This contradicts the fact that $x$ is contained in a unique Cartan algebra and we deduce that $\lambda(x)\neq 0$.

This finishes the proof: $L_\lambda$ are also eigenspaces of $ad(x)$ and we have shown that $\lambda(x)$ is never $0$. Thus, the nullspace of $ad(x)$ is exactly $L_0=\mathfrak{a}.$

Comment: Why $L_\lambda + \mathbb Fx $ is a CSA? I see that it is its own CSA, but I cant see why it is a CSA of $L$. Thank you.

Comment: No, it's not a CSA, but $\mathbb{F}y+\mathbb{F}x$ is abelian so it is contained in a CSA. Of course, it cannot be $\mathfrak{a}$ since it contains $y$.

Comment: I can see it now, great!

Comment: This proof uses that the CSA is split, which is not true in general if $\mathbb F$ is not algebraically closed. I guess one could reduce to that case by scalar extension, but it should at least be mentioned.

Comment: Actually, the step in the comment "$\mathbb{F} y + \mathbb {F}x$ is abelian so it is contained in a CSA" is not true either. Many abelian subalgebras are not contained in CSA's, you need additionally that all its elements are semisimple.

Comment: Sorry, but I actually don't see straightforward ways around both problems pointed out in my recent comments. I downvote for the time being but will be happy to upvote once these are fixed.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thank you very much for your objections, it was really fun to try to fix my proof. I edited for your second objection and I'll think about whether I can assume $\mathbb{F}$ is algebraically closed using extension by scalars.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if there's some way to do this without $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triples, but at least that solves that problem. Removing my downvote and looking forward to a fix of the other issue for an upvote (I am trying to think of something too).

Comment: I finally found a proof which works in general, see my answer. Although it looks very different from yours, I actually was led there by using your idea; all the business about $C_L(x)$ being reductive, and finding different CSAs in its semisimple part, came from the idea that you had there with a specific $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple. The essential idea is the same: If the centraliser of our $x$ is not just abelian i.e. a CSA itself, then it must contain something semisimple, which is so big that it makes room for several CSAs. +1, finally.

Answer (score 3):

I've finally found a proof which works for any (finite-dimensional) semisimple Lie algebra $L$ over an arbitrary field of characteristic $0$ (and possibly even more). It rests on several "well-known" facts, which, however, when you don't accept them as well-known, are not exactly trivial. In the following, the reference "Bourbaki" is obviously to their books on *Lie Groups and Algebras*, actually all to chapter VII of that.

Remember that the general definition of a Cartan subalgebra of *any* Lie algebra is: a subalgebra which is nilpotent and self-normalising. For semisimple Lie algebras, this is equivalent to being a maximal toral subalgebra, where a subalgebra is called "toral" if it is abelian and consists of $ad$-semisimple elements. Cf. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1071417/96384), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3537312/96384), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3481364/96384), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3605085/96384).

**Fact 1**: If $x \in L$ is an $ad$-semisimple element, then
$$\lbrace \text{Cartan subalgebras of } L \text{ containing } x \rbrace = \lbrace \text{Cartan subalgebras of } C_L(x) \rbrace. $$

(This is a special case  of Bourbaki, chap. VII, §2 no. 3 Proposition 10, where indeed we don't need $L$ to be semisimple. The inclusion "$\subseteq$" is straightforward in particular in the case of semisimple $L$, from the known equivalence of the definitions in that case. For "$\supseteq$",  let $\mathfrak h$ be a CSA of $C_L(x)$. Clearly $\mathfrak h$ is nilpotent and contains $x$. Further, if $N:=N_L(\mathfrak h)$ is the normaliser of $\mathfrak h$ in $L$, then because $ad(x)(N) \subseteq \mathfrak h$ and $x$ is $ad$-semisimple, there is a decomposition into $ad(x)$-stable vector spaces $N = \mathfrak h \oplus M$ where further $ad(x)(M) = 0$, meaning that $M$ and hence all of $N$ is contained in $C_L(x)$. But then $N = N_{\color{red}{C_L(x)}}(\mathfrak h)$ which, by $\mathfrak h$ being a CSA in $C_L(x)$, is just $=\mathfrak h$.)

**Fact 2**: If $x \in L$ is a semisimple element, then its centraliser $C_L(x)$ is a reductive Lie algebra.

(See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2101071/96384), although the proof there uses an algebraically closed field / *split* semisimple $L$, but then it's really straightforward to reduce to that case: Because the centraliser in a scalar extension is the scalar extension of the centraliser, and a Lie algebra is reductive iff its scalar extension is. Actually, the stronger fact that for any toral subalgebra $\mathfrak a \subset L$, the centraliser $C_L(\mathfrak a)$ is a reductive Lie algebra, is Corollary 3.1.21 in [my thesis](https://smf.emath.fr/publications/algebres-de-lie-semi-simples-et-leur-classification-sur-les-corps-p-adiques), where it's also proved via scalar extension. It is also a special case of Bourbaki, chap. VII §1 no. 5 Proposition 13.)

**Fact 3**: The Cartan subalgebras of a reductive Lie algebra $\mathfrak r$, written as $\mathfrak z \oplus \mathfrak s$ with centre $\mathfrak z$ and semisimple $\mathfrak s$,  are exactly the subalgebras of the form $\mathfrak z \oplus \mathfrak c$ where $\mathfrak c$ is a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak s$.

(This should be clear from the general definition of CSAs as subalgebras which are nilpotent and self-normalising; indeed, in Bourbaki chap VII §2 no. 1 it is mentioned right after that definition that the only CSA of any nilpotent Lie algebra (in particular, an abelian one like $\mathfrak z$) is itself, and it is Proposition 2 that the CSAs of a direct product are the direct products of the CSAs.)

**Fact 4**: Any semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak s \neq 0$ contains more than one CSA.

(Not as trivial as it sounds. But for sure there are many ways to see this in general: Indeed, Bourbaki shows that over any infinite field, every non-nilpotent Lie algebra contains infinitely many CSAs (see my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4346792/96384)). Here is an ad hoc argument: W.l.o.g. $\mathfrak s$ is simple. In a semisimple Lie algebra, every element can be decomposed into a semisimple and a nilpotent part which commute. Basically, we have to find two semisimple elements $x_1, x_2$ which don't commute, because then $x_1$ is contained in a CSA which, by virtue of being abelian (toral!), cannot contain $x_2$, and vice versa, so there are at least two different CSAs. -- Now, if $\mathfrak s$ contains no nonzero nilpotent (this happens, e.g. compact forms over $\mathbb R$), then all its elements are semisimple, but since $\mathfrak s$ is not abelian we are done. So assume there is a nilpotent element $y$. Then, like in Levent's answer, we extend $y$ to an $\mathfrak sl_2$-triple $y,h,z$ and can explicitly find non-commuting semisimple elements from that, e.g. like in his answer, or we note that the inner automorphism $e^{ad(y)}$ of $\mathfrak s$ sends the semisimple $h$ to the semisimple $h \mp 2 y$ (sign depending on how you define $\mathfrak sl_2$-triples), and these two do not commute with each other.)

---

Now let's go, let $x$ be a semisimple element of $L$. By facts 2, 3, and 4, the Lie algebra $C_L(x)$, in and of itself, contains a unique CSA if and only if it is abelian, if and only if it is itself a CSA (in itself); otherwise it contains several CSAs.

Via fact 1, this translates to:

There is a unique CSA in $L$ containing $x$ if and only if $C_L(x)$ is a CSA in $L$; which by your definition is equivalent to $x$ being regular.

Comment: +1, it's such a nice proof. While I was trying to improve my proof, I more or less reduced it to the case you consider: Can I show that $C_L(x)$ contains at least two CSAs? I tried to prove this using only extension by scalars but I failed (possibly due to the fact that I know so little about Lie algebras over non-algebraically closed fields). Do you think that it's possible?

Comment: @Levent: I think it boils down to Fact 4, as this is a special case of the statement we're after: In any simple Lie algebra $L$, $L=C_L(0)$ contains more than one CSA. This seems ridiculously simple, yet I don't see a proof with scalar extension. The problem is that usually the scalar extension has "many more" CSAs which do not "come from" CSAs of the original algebra. Likewise, the approach with sl_2-triples runs into the problem that over general fields, $L$ might not even contain nonzero nilpotent elements (like $\mathfrak{su}_n$ over $\mathbb R$). So I doubt. But I'd like to be surprised.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'm still a little bit confusing on the last few paragraphs. In the "let's go" paragraph, you said that *($C_L(x)$) is abelian, if and only if it is itself a CSA (in itself)*. You emphasised "*in itself*", but in the final paragraph, you used that  $C_L(x)$ is a CSA in $L$. Is this not quite coherent? I think in the "let's go" paragraph, we can indeed claim that  **$C_L(x)$ is abelian iff $C_L(x)$ is a CSA of $L$**. In fact, for the if part, since $L$ is semisimple, as a CSA, $C_L(x)$ is a maximal toral subalgebra, which is abelian. ......

Comment: ...... For the only if part, $C_L(x)$ is abelian, hence nilpotent. To show $C_L(x)$ is a CSA, we need to check that it is self-normalizing. To do that, let $y \in L$, $z \in C_L(x)$, we shall show $[y,z] \in C_L(x)$, i.e. $[[y,z],x]=0$. By Jacobi identity, it suffices to show that $[[z,x],y]=0$ and $[[x,y],z] =0$. For the first, $[z,x]=0$ since $z \in C_L(x)$. For the second one, note that $[x,y] \in C_L(x)$ since $x \in C_L(x)$, and use that $C_L(x)$ is abelian, $[z, [x,y]]=0$. To sum up, $C_L(x)$ is self-normalizing. Hence, $C_L(x)$ is indeed a CSA of $L$.

Comment: The "only if" part uses the crucial condition that $C_L(x)$ is abelian, which depends highly on **Fact 1-4**. It seems that (as the above "proof" in the comment implies) "$C_L(x)$ is self-normalizing* does not hold in general. So the above "proof" in the comment did not simplify the proof of the question in this post, and your reductions in **Fact 1-4** are still indispensable. Sorry for the late and lengthy comments. Is there something trivial that I have missed to cause such troubles? Thank you so much!

Comment: @HetongXu: I don't think you can conclude "$[x,y] \in C_L(x)$ since $x \in C_L(x)$". Actually, to show $[x,y] \in C_L(x)$ at that point is almost circular and will not work without using e.g. that $x$ is semisimple (note the claim is false for general $x$ even in simple Lie algebras). The only way to prove it which I know is (a proof of) fact 1, which is why I present it in this way. I emphasize "in itself", and then, *only with using fact 1*, we can conclude about anything that happens outside of $C_L(x)$ in all of $L$. (You seem to have missed my line "Via fact 1, this translates to:").

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: Thank you for your reply. It seems that I took it for granted that $C_L(x)$ is an ideal of $L$, which is actually merely a subalgebra of $L$. Sorry for that and thank you for your further hint! :)

Comment: @Levent: Need help. I just reread what I wrote and I do not understand my own argument in step 4 where I say that if all semisimple elements commute with each other, they form an ideal. I see that they would form a subalgebra, but that does not lead to anything. Do you know what I might have thought there? -- If not, as an alternative idea I have this case distinction: If $\mathfrak s$ contains a nonzero nilpotent, then concluding via an $sl_2$-triple like in your answer. If not, then *all* its elements are semisimple, hence they cannot all commute because $\mathfrak s$ is not abelian.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg We need to prove that every simple Lie algebra contains semisimple elements that do not commute. It sounds very simple but I don't see a way to show this without using Jacobson-Morozov theorem at the moment.

Comment: @Levent: Repaired it I think. Indeed, Jacobson-Morozov for an ad hoc argument. However, I linked to Bourbaki quotes in a different question which do not rely on Jacobson-Morozov (or semisimplicity) at all and show that any non-nilpotent LA contains infinitely many CSA's; the downside is, one needs a little Zariski topology and denseness of regular elements. Funny how such "obvious" things need intricate reasoning.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I gave a big thought on this problem and still cannot see any other way without using JM / $sl_2$ triples. Indeed, it is really surprising.